# How to select one name in between dates form mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I will explain this as much as possible.

I have a project which need to show the names from database to `textboxes`. I have 2 `datetimepicker` for searching between dates and 5 `textboxes` to show the names in mysql database. for example I select the from start date 2018/12/07 and end date 2019/01/07 in the `datagridview` it will show all the rows and columns in-between dates. However, I need the names to show on my 5 textboxes. I don't have a code since I don't know where to begin with.

In `mysqldatabase` I have only id,name,dateofentry.

In my `form` :

- `datetimepicker1` = `startdate`
- `datetimepicker2` = `enddate`
- `button1` = `generatebutton`
- `textbox1` = `nametxt1`
- `textbox2` = `nametxt2`
- `textbox3` = `nametxt3`
- `textbox4` = `nametxt4`
- `textbox5` = `nametxt5`

**Update** when I use this:

```
mysqlconn.Open()
COMMAND.Connection = mysqlconn 
COMMAND.CommandText = "Select name from table1 where dateofentry between '" & Format(Me.startdate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND '" & Format(Me.endtime.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'" 
Dim sqlresult1 As Object 
sqlresult1 = COMMAND.ExecuteScalar 
Dim str1 As String 
str1 = sqlresult1 
nametxt1.Text = str1  
mysqlconn.Close()
```

The same name shows in each of my 5 textboxes

Thank you for answering this question.

Comment: Please use the `edit` button under your question to add further information. I've done that for you in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanations and comments in-line.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'The Using block ensures that your database objects are closed and disposed
    'even if there is an error
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
        'Pass the Select statement and the connection to the constructor of the command
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select name from table1 where dateofentry between @Date1 AND @Date2;", cn)
            'Use parameters
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date1", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date2", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value
            'open the connection at the last possible moment
            cn.Open()
            'Execute scalar only returns the first row, first column of the result set
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    'Then a little link magic to dump the first column of the table
    'to an array
    Dim names() = (From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
                   Select row(0)).ToArray
    'If there are less than 5 records returned this
    'code will fail, Add a check for this and
    'adjest your code accordingly
    TextBox1.Text = names(0).ToString
    TextBox2.Text = names(1).ToString
    TextBox3.Text = names(2).ToString
    TextBox4.Text = names(3).ToString
    TextBox5.Text = names(4).ToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `tblPerson`
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2018-12-30 14:15:55' AND '2019-01-06 10:15:55')
LIMIT 5;

text1.text = dt.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
text2.text = dt.Rows[1]["name"].ToString();
text3.text = dt.Rows[2]["name"].ToString();
text4.text = dt.Rows[3]["name"].ToString();
text5.text = dt.Rows[4]["name"].ToString();
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your quick response. I try this one but there's an error on `Character is not valid.` and `Identifier expected`